# In JBPM sub process, when we are iterating through multi instance , the values are passing as null for the iterating elements

Tags: workflow, jbpm, bpmn, bpmn.io

In the above subprocess, we are passing the arraylist from Main process and we are iterating the list in multi instace of [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtnAR.png)subprocess. The getServiceData collection is iterating as eachItem object. When we are running these subprocess along with main process in the Eclipse. The eachItem an eachItemOutput are passing as null and it is not invoking the reusable task in the multi instance. Could you please share your thoughts and help us on this error.

We have tried to run the JBPM process in the eclipse.
Expectation : The process should pick up arraylist of requests using multi instance it should trigger a single request to subsystem and return the array of responses.
output : currently we are getting null values when we are iterating the multi instance in sub process.